# How to use data from a Webservice on Eclipse to populate a database in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, web-services

I want to be able to use my web service to be able to populate a database in MySQL. From the code below, I have connected to the database that I want to populate. How can I use the data that users import on my Web Service to populate MySQL database **exchangeInformation**. The Web service is working and everything works. I am just looking to be able to use the input of that data from the web service to populate my database in MySQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Code Below:

```
 package org.example.www.newwsdlfile3;

 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class JavaMYSQL {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

getConnection(); 

}
public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
try{
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exchangeinformation";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "admin";
    Class.forName(driver);

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    System.out.println("Connected");
    return conn;
 } catch (Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}

 return null;
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) to see an example of creating a statement from a connection object and executing a query with it. As to your webservice information, I do not see where you are passing it in. That said you can use some simple string replacement to handle that:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tableName values(':value1', ':value2',':value3', etc)";
sql = sql.replace(":value1", dataFromService);
```

Something along those lines should get you started.

**EDIT FOR CLARITY:**

```
  String sql = "INSERT INTO tableName values(':value1', ':value2',':value3', etc)";
String dataFromService = "EDIT";
sql = sql.replace(":value1", dataFromService);
System.out.println(sql);
```

Would net you an output:
    INSERT INTO tableName values('EDIT',':value2','value3', etc)

Comment: when I fill out the sql.replace(:value1, datafromService) how exactly should that be. For example if I have SponsorOrganizationIdentifier as value1, how can I get it to pull in the data from my webservice value of SponsorOrganizationIdentifier?

Comment: it is pure string replacement. So the value you want to pass it needs to be something that will concat with a string. So, you would treat it as any time you would print that value out. As long as you are passing it the value you want to search for: ie the SponsorOrganizationIdentifier is = 5, it would replace value1 with 5 in the sql string. The same as doing a "values('+SponsorOrganizationIdentifier+',..etc)"

Comment: ok so for values 2 and values 3, how would I write those in? Could I put it beside (:value1, :value2, :value3, etc, datafromService)? or should I write them out like this: sql.replace(:value1, dataFromService); sql.replace(:value2, dataFromService);

Comment: The most clear way that I am aware of is to write them as individual calls like you suggest as your second option. Remember, this method is looking    for a char sequence target followed by the char sequence to replace it with.

Comment: If I replace int dataFromService = 5 with String dataFromService = getSponsorOrganizationalIdentifier will that work. The problem is that I don't know what the SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier is until the user enters it so I don't want to replace it with 5. I want to replace it with what he or she enters on my webservice. For example if they are prompted with SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier from my WebService and they enter xyz, I want xyz to be populated in my database under the SponsorOrganizationalIdentitiferColumn.

Comment: It's totally fine. As long as java will allow you to concat the value into a string it works. The 5 is just an example. It just needs to be a char sequence when passing it into .replace(). If the .replace() is your hangup you could declare the sql string after you have the values from your webservice as 
    String sql = "Some string"+value1+","+value2; and so on but the .replace makes the structure of the sql string more understandable for later codereview. It also ensures you dont have to worry about excaping single quotes in the sql string.

Comment: Also, had a brain fart. Don't forget to set the sql string = to the sql.replace() value. That method returns a new string with the replaced value, it does not modify the current string. Immutable stuffs and all

Comment: Ok I understand everything except the int dataFromService = 5. How can I change that to String SponsorOrganizationalIdentifier = (What a user enters in) I don't want to pre-define a value for it. I want to set it up where whatever value is entered into my SponsorOrganizationIdentifier class is imported into my database. With the current example you have, it has int = 5 and that would enter 5 into my database. I want the value it =s too to come from the web service. I am sorry if you are explaining it the right way, I just don't understand it

Comment: So, it doesn't need to be predefined. You would pass any kind of variable into the replace that can be parsed into the string. So, whatever type of object they pass in, you would use the object to pass the value into the replace. So, if they pass a value and it gets added to an object, you could use the parameter's geter to pass the value into the string. All you are doing, is passing a value into the method to replace the substring that is acting as a place holder. So, however it is that you are passing that webservice value into the program is where you will pass the value into the string

Comment: Ok I think where I am confused as to how does it know where to pass the data for multiple values. For example I have like 180 values that could be filled out in this web service. For example I have (firstname, lastname, etc) sql = sql.replace(":firstname", dataFromService); sql = sql.replace(":lastname", dataFromService) how do I define from which option that is coming from. I want to say for firstname, populate first name column. I just don't see how it maps to the values from my web service. I thought Id have to declare the variable I want the response from to be put into my database.

Comment: I think I see the disconnect. Yes, you will have to declare the variable. This is just a way to replace the placeholder in the sql string. So, if you have a firstname variable, you will want to pass that into a .replace() that matches the placeholder for firstname in your database. There's no behind the scenes mapping taking place. You would just use the sql = sql.replace(); for each different value you want to replace a placeholder with. If there are 180 values that could get passed in then you would need 180 statements.

Comment: If you really have that many values you may not want to use the .replace() function but instead create a loop to append the values to the sql string to be used. However, this would require some validation because the database is going to be expecting them in the correct order to match the db columns.

Comment: I am ok with writing 180 statements, but I am just having trouble declaring the variable I am working with. I have it in another .java file, but im not sure how to use it. I am really new with java and just learning on my way so I want to thank you for answering all my questions :)

Comment: Ok, well if you would be ok with it, if I have answered the original question please select it as answered. If you have that object in another file, you will need to import it. The answer I have given includes a link to the java documentation which may also help guide you in your importing of another object to be used. Also, I see that you are returning a connection and never closing it. Make sure with all db connections that once you are finished, or if there is an error you make sure to .close() it. That can lead to later issues.

Comment: I suggest that you define the problem as it is now and search for the answer here on stack overflow. If there isn't already a solution, you can repost with more code detail of the now current problem you are having. That way more people will be able to jump in and help

Comment: That's what we are here for! Hope you get it all sorted out.

Comment: How would the prepared statements and everything work at the top? I passed in my web service information, now I am looking to use the prepared statements and such. Could you give me an example of that?

Comment: Check the link in my original answer. It will take you directly to a tutorial with explanations and examples that are better/more clear than anything I could write.